# NuCaptcha not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, captcha

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    window
        .fetch('https://services.share-pi.aarp.org/applications/CoreServices/WSOWebService/captcha/getWidget')
        .then((resp) => resp.text())
        .then(data => {
           
      // Initialize the DOM parser
            var parser = new window.DOMParser()
           
            // Parse the text
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html')
       
            // Print to console
            console.log(doc.documentElement)
            document.getElementById('nuCaptcha').appendChild(doc.documentElement)
        })
})
```

```html
<h3>NuCaptcha</h3>
<div id="nuCaptcha" class=""></div>
```

I'm implementing a NuCaptcha - similar to Google Captcha.

I'm printing the response of my request into the console. When i paste this response into JSBin or a blank .html . file, it works and the captcha challenge displays but the captcha added to the page doesn't seem to be rendering.

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Hi @Paul Mackey , could you please add your code as a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to your question? Reason being that links can become obsolete.

Comment: Just added it as a runnable snippet now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to execute the scripts after pasting the downloaded html.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 window.fetch('https://services.share-pi.aarp.org/applications/CoreServices/WSOWebService/captcha/getWidget').then((resp) => resp.text()).then(data => {
  var div = document.getElementById('nuCaptcha');
  div.innerHTML = data;
  var script = div.getElementsByTagName('script')
  for (var i = 0; i < script.length; i++) eval(script[i].innerHTML);
 })
})
```

```html
<h3>NuCaptcha</h3>
<div id="nuCaptcha" class=""></div>
```